# What is the intuition behind the $\clubsuit$ axiom?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

In my seminar, we've talked about applications of $\clubsuit$ in forming $\omega_1$-compact spaces. I'm comfortable with stating $\clubsuit$ and it's use within the proofs, but is there any "nice" intuition behind the statement of $\clubsuit$? It seems fairly convoluted and artificial.

Edit: The $\clubsuit$ principle states that there is a sequence of subsets of $\omega_1$, $A_\lambda$, such that $A_\lambda$ is cofinal in $\lambda$ for all limit $\lambda$ and for any uncountable $F \subset \omega_1$, there is a $\lambda$ such that $A_\lambda \subset F$.

Comment: $\lozenge-\sf CH.$

Comment: Also, Shelah has a nice approach to mathematics. Write a proof, then move some (or all) of the proof into an axiom, or weaken the axiom you've used to exactly what is needed for the proof to work. So they can feel convoluted without having the appropriate context. In the case of $\clubsuit$, and I might be misremembering, this was the Whitehead problem, and the question of whether or not CH is enough, so $\clubsuit$ is "what you need to prove the Whitehead problem" out of $\lozenge$. If I remember correctly, which I might not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's a wonderful bit of information to know. Thank you.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: $\clubsuit$ was actually introduced by Adam Ostaszewski in *A perfectly normal countably compact scattered space which is not strongly zero-dimensional*, J. London Math. Soc. (2), 14(1):167-177, 1976. He used $\clubsuit+\mathsf{CH}$ to construct it; it was not then known that this combination is equivalent to $\diamondsuit$. (The space in question is also hereditarily separable and first countable and has a base of compact, countable, clopen sets, and open sets are either countable or co-countable.)

Comment: @Brian: You know, I actually knew that at some point. It makes sense because Assaf Rinot has a paper about the "Ostazewski square" which is a combination of $\clubsuit$ and $\square$. That raises the question of why did I misremember Shelah having to do with that... Hmm.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think that he may have been the one who showed that $\clubsuit+\mathsf{CH}=\diamondsuit$.